# Is it possible to install supervisord inside virtualenv?

Tags: python, supervisord

Currenty I install supervisord system-wide on Ubuntu with `apt-get install supervisor`. All my projects are inside virtualenvs, so system-wide Python is not really used for anything.

Is it possible to install supervisor inside my virtualenvs? Can I run multiple instances?

Comment: you can install supervisor inside virtualenvs using pip install supervisor.  visit http://supervisord.org/installing.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. You can first setup a `virtualenv` and then install supervisor use `pip`.

```
virtualenv env
cd env
./bin/pip install supervisor
```

create configuration file:

```
echo_supervisord_conf > /path_to_configuration_file/supervisord.conf
```

You can run multiple instances, just use different port supervisord listen on in configuration file:

```
port=127.0.0.1:9001
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can, even when supervisor is not installed system-wide.

Go to your virtualenv directory and activate your env. Then install supervisor using pip:

`pip install supervisor`

After its successfull installation, run:

`which supervisord`

Here you can see the path of supervisord command which will be inside your virtualenv only.

Now the most important part. When you run 'supervisord' command it will look for config file whose default location is: /etc/supervisord.conf

But in case supervisor is installed *only* in virtualenv it will throw an error like this :

**Error: No config file found at default paths.**

Now to run supervisor you need to create your own config file for supervisor and specify its path when running it.
To do that, first run:

`echo_supervisord_conf > supervisord.conf`

This will create a default supervisor config file in your current working directory. 
Configure your supervisord.conf file (see http://supervisord.org/configuration.html), and then run supervisor using '-c' option:

`supervisord -c supervisord.conf`

Source: http://supervisord.org/installing.html